# Stopping a re-named Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a game that creates 'bots' which wander around a map aimlessly. Every time the player clicks a button, a new Thread is created which creates the bot. If you press the button numerous times, numerous bots are made all with the same Thread name botThread.

However I want to be able to differentiate between the bots so I can stop individual bots. So I have used the setName() function to change the name of the first bot to "Bot 1", but if I try Bot1.stop(), it says the Thread doesn't exist? (I know I shouldn't use .stop() method).

However, if I get an error in the Thread it says " Exception in thread "Bot 1"". So it clearly does exist!

Here is some of my code:

```
public class botGame{

Thread botThread;

public void newBot(){

botThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

      public void run(){

             botThread.setName("Bot 1");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better alternative to my other answer would be to have the bots keep track of their own threads:

```
class Bot {
    Thread thread = null;
    private String name;
    volatile boolean stop = false;
    Bot(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void run() {
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                while(!stop) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
    public void stop() {
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

And in you bot-creating code do this:

```
public class botGame{
    Map<String, Bot> bots = new Map<String, Bot>();

    public void makeNewBot(String name) {
        bots.put(name, new(Bot(name)));
    }

    public void startBot(String name) {
        bots.get(name).run();  // TODO: Add check for wrong name
    }

    public void stopBot(String name) {
        bots.get(name).stop(); // TODO: Add check for wrong name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The thread name is simply a useful identifier for debugging your code. It is *completely unrelated* to any variables, objects or identifiers in your applications.

In other words: Calling `thread.setName("foo")` does *not* magically allow you to call `foo.stop()`.

What you want to do instead is hold the `Thread` objects you created in some collection or map, retrieve it from there and manipulate it then (ideally **not** using `stop()`, as you noted).

For example, instead of a single `botThread` field, you'd have this:

```
Collection<Thread> botThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
```

and when you start a thread you do this:

```
Thread botThread = new Thread( ... );
botThread.start();
botThreads.add(botThread);
```

And since we're on the topic of avoiding stop: If you don't hold on to the `Thread` object, but to a `BotRunnable` instead, you can add a `pleaseStop` method to that `BotRunnable` that sets a `volatile boolean` field named `keepRunning` (or similar) to `false`. Then, inside the `run` method, periodically check that field and if it's `false`, simply return.

Answer (score 3):

try to put your thread in a list, so you can go on the element you want, and delete it

Comment: any container with a variable size, in fact

Comment: inside your button click method, you can put the thread with it's name into a map

Comment: @shan: "better" depends a lot on *how* he needs to access them. If he just needs to get "all of them" or "any one", then a collection is just fine.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, yes, he has mentioned that he uses a name to identify the thread. in that case i think map is better, because it is a key,value pair

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
public class botGame{
  Map<String, Thread> botThreads = new Map<String, Thread>();
  public void newBot(){
  Thread botThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      }
    };
  botThreads.put("Bot 1", botThread);
}
```

I have not checked my example closely for errors and also you need a way of creating threads with different names, but I think you can get the idea of the map.

To find a thread object, do `Thread thread = botThreads.get("Bot 1");`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the thread name, you could monitor a Statefull class or a Map that would give the thread permission to run or not.

So once the permission to run is lost, your thread just ends by itself.

Answer (score -1):

The method  `Thread.stop()`
 should not be used. It is deprecated for a reason - 
[deprecation reason](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29). Use `volatile boolean`flag in the thread to check whether it should stop or not. Set the flag in the main thread when you want to stop it.